# Flutter `showModalBottomSheet` Ticker was not disposed during tests

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-test

When writing a Flutter widget test I'm running into an error where the Ticker that was created during showModalBottomSheet() is not being disposed of.

I think I understand if I'm implementing my own Flutter animation I should make an AnimationController, and I would call `AnimationController.dispose()` during the widget `dispose` method.

However, since (I believe) the AnimationController is abstracted away to provide some convenience I'm not sure where or how to make sure the widget is disposed of after the tests are done.

Note: the code works and when I'm testing on the simulator/emulator the modal bottom sheet is great. I just want to be able to test it in a `testWidgets` test.

I've looked at the showModalBottomSheet documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html but that has only shown how to use the function. I'm not finding any way to control when I can dispose of the animation.

#### test_test.dart

(extra `pump()` in there in case of an async issue but it doesn't seem to help)

```dart
testWidgets('Taping edit score button brings up bottom sheet to edit',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    setUp();
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: GameList(
        game: Game(players: players),
      ),
    ));
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('p1-edit-score')));
    await tester.pump();
    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.byKey(Key('test')), findsOneWidget);
    await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('tap-me')));
    await tester.pump();
    await tester.pump();
    tearDown();
  });
```

#### game_view.dart

```dart
class GameView extends StatefulWidget {
  GameView({@required this.playerList, @required this.onResetPlayerScores});

  final Function onResetPlayerScores;
  final List<Player> playerList;

  @override
  _GameState createState() => _GameState();
}

class _GameState extends State<GameView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: GameList(
        game: Game(players: widget.playerList),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### game_list.dart

some widgets taken out for brevity

```dart
class GameList extends StatefulWidget {
  GameList({@required this.game});

  final Game game;

  @override
  GameListState createState() => GameListState(game: game);
}

class GameListState extends State<GameList> {
  GameListState({@required this.game});

  final Game game;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: game.players.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Card(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListTile(
                trailing: Text(
                  '${game.players[index].score.toInt()}',
                ),
                title: Text(
                  '${game.players[index].name}',
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.edit,
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      _settingModalBottomSheet(context);
                    },
                    key: Key(
                      '${game.players[index].name}-edit-score',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(),
    );
  }
}

void _settingModalBottomSheet(context) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
      return Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'edit',
                key: Key('test'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
                title: Text('Video'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context, 'video');
                },
                key: Key('tap-me'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

#### short Output of `flutter test`. The most important part I think.

```
OverlayState created a Ticker via its TickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called
on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. All Tickers must be disposed before calling
super.dispose(). Tickers used by AnimationControllers should be disposed by calling dispose() on the
AnimationController itself. Otherwise, the ticker will leak.
```

#### full output of `flutter test`

````
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
OverlayState#bfe06(tickers: tracking 1 ticker, entries: [OverlayEntry#c26ee(opaque: false;
maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#7cd4f(opaque: false; maintainState: true),
OverlayEntry#d496e(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#e9ad3(opaque: false;
maintainState: true)]) was disposed with an active Ticker.
OverlayState created a Ticker via its TickerProviderStateMixin, but at the time dispose() was called
on the mixin, that Ticker was still active. All Tickers must be disposed before calling
super.dispose(). Tickers used by AnimationControllers should be disposed by calling dispose() on the
AnimationController itself. Otherwise, the ticker will leak.
The offending ticker was: _WidgetTicker(created by OverlayState#bfe06(tickers: tracking 0 tickers,
entries: [OverlayEntry#c26ee(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#7cd4f(opaque: false;
maintainState: true)]))
The stack trace when the _WidgetTicker was actually created was:
#0      new Ticker.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:64:40)
#1      new Ticker (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:66:6)
#2      new _WidgetTicker (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:225:80)
#3      _OverlayState&State&TickerProviderStateMixin.createTicker
(package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:161:34)
#4      new AnimationController (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:245:21)
#5      BottomSheet.createAnimationController
(package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:128:12)
#6      _ModalBottomSheetRoute.createAnimationController
(package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:356:40)
#7      TransitionRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:176:19)
#8      ModalRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:907:11)
#9      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1754:11)
#10     Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1093:34)
#11     showModalBottomSheet (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:427:20)
#12     _settingModalBottomSheet (package:score_keeper/game_list.dart:98:3)
#13     GameListState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:score_keeper/game_list.dart:65:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
#15     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
#16     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#17     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
#18     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:312:7)
#19     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
#20
_TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding.handleEvent
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
#21
_TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
(package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
#22     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:365:11)
#23     WidgetTester.sendEventToBinding.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:458:15)
#25     WidgetTester.sendEventToBinding.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:457:39)
#28     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
#29     WidgetTester.sendEventToBinding (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:457:27)
#30     TestGesture.up.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/test_pointer.dart:422:13)
#32     TestGesture.up.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/test_pointer.dart:420:39)
#35     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
#36     TestGesture.up (package:flutter_test/src/test_pointer.dart:420:27)
#37     WidgetController.tapAt.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:263:21)
#51     WidgetController.startGesture (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart)
#75     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1026:17)
#77     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1014:35)
(elided 58 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package
stack_trace)


When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _OverlayState&State&TickerProviderStateMixin.dispose.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:178:13)
#1      _OverlayState&State&TickerProviderStateMixin.dispose (package:flutter/src/widgets/ticker_provider.dart:191:6)
#2      StatefulElement.unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4107:12)
#3      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1737:13)
#4      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#5      ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#6      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#7      _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5080:14)
#9      _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#10     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#11     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#12     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#13     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#14     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5080:14)
#15     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#16     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5080:14)
#18     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#19     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#20     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#21     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#22     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#23     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#24     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#25     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#26     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#27     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#28     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#29     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#30     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#31     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#32     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#33     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#34     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#35     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#36     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#37     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#38     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#39     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#40     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#41     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#42     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#43     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#44     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#45     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#46     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#47     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#48     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#49     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#50     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5080:14)
#51     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#52     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#53     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#54     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#55     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#56     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#57     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#58     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#59     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#60     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#61     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#62     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#63     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#64     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#65     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#66     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#67     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#68     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5080:14)
#69     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#70     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#71     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#72     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#73     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#74     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#75     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#76     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#77     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#78     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#79     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#80     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#81     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#82     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#83     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#84     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#85     _InactiveElements._unmount.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1735:7)
#86     ComponentElement.visitChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3955:14)
#87     _InactiveElements._unmount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1733:13)
#88     ListIterable.forEach (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:39:13)
#89     _InactiveElements._unmountAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1746:25)
#90     BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2426:27)
#91     BuildOwner.lockState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2258:15)
#92     BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2425:7)
#93     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:953:18)
#94     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285:5)
#95     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1016:15)
#96     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:958:9)
#97     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:915:5)
#98     runApp (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:787:7)
#99     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:637:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#102    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:613:14)
#103    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1010:24)
#109    AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1007:15)
#110    testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:116:22)
#111    Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#112    Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:250:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#117    Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:247:5)
#118    Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:166:33)
#123    Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:165:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#124    Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:400:25)
<asynchronous suspension>
#138    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)
#139    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)
#140    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
(elided 28 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SCHEDULER LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
An animation is still running even after the widget tree was disposed.

There was one transient callback left. The stack trace for when it was registered is as follows:
── callback 72 ──
#0      new _FrameCallbackEntry.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:112:33)
#1      new _FrameCallbackEntry (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:115:6)
#2      _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:459:49)
#3      Ticker.scheduleTick (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:243:46)
#4      Ticker.start (package:flutter/src/scheduler/ticker.dart:159:7)
#5      AnimationController._startSimulation (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:685:41)
#6      AnimationController._animateToInternal (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:590:12)
#7      AnimationController.forward (package:flutter/src/animation/animation_controller.dart:458:12)
#8      TransitionRoute.didPush (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:188:24)
#9      ModalRoute.didPush (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:917:18)
#10     NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1756:11)
#11     Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1093:34)
#12     showModalBottomSheet (package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart:427:20)
#13     _settingModalBottomSheet (package:score_keeper/game_list.dart:98:3)
#14     GameListState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:score_keeper/game_list.dart:65:23)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:635:14)
#16     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:711:32)
#17     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
#18     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:365:11)
#19     TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:312:7)
#20     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
#21     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
#22     _TestWidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
#23     TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:365:11)
#24     WidgetTester.sendEventToBinding.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:458:15)
#26     WidgetTester.sendEventToBinding.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:457:39)
#29     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
#30     WidgetTester.sendEventToBinding (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:457:27)
#31     TestGesture.up.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/test_pointer.dart:422:13)
#33     TestGesture.up.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/test_pointer.dart:420:39)
#36     TestAsyncUtils.guard (package:flutter_test/src/test_async_utils.dart:69:41)
#37     TestGesture.up (package:flutter_test/src/test_pointer.dart:420:27)
#38     WidgetController.tapAt.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart:263:21)
#52     WidgetController.startGesture (package:flutter_test/src/controller.dart)
#76     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1026:17)
#78     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1014:35)
(elided 58 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
00:04 +25 -1: /Users/tsustare/src/projects/flutter-score-keeper/score_keeper/test/game_view_test.dart: Taping edit score button brings up bottom sheet to edit [E]
  Test failed. See exception logs above.
  The test description was: Taping edit score button brings up bottom sheet to edit```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try tapping any visible widget that isn't in the bottom sheet and triggering a frame before the end of your test. This will dismiss the bottom sheet and dispose of it's `AnimationContoller` before the test exits.

For example at the end of your test:

```
await tester.tap(find.byType(BackButtonIcon)); // any widget that isn't in the bottom sheet
await tester.pump();
```

Answer (score 7):

I had similar behavior when I was testing. Solve after change

```
 await tester.pump();
```

for

```
 await tester.pumpAndSettle();
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `pump` twice did the trick for me:

```
      expect(find.byKey(Key('BottomSheetKey')), findsNothing);
      await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('MyButton'))); //calls showModalBottomSheet(...) when tapped
      await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 1));
      await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 1));
      expect(find.byKey(Key('BottomSheetKey')), findsOneWidget);
```